# Botframework Pattern is giving me errors with regular easy regex expressions for email

Tags: botframework

I tried this pattern for email with my bot but it does not work published on skype. It always reject any normal valid email.

```
[Describe("email "), Prompt(QuestionWhatIsYour)]
[Pattern(@"^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$")]
public string Email;
```

I also tried

```
[Pattern(@"^[\w!#$%&'*+\-/=?\^_`{|}~]+(\.[\w!#$%&'*+\-/=?\^_`{|}~]+)*((([\-\w]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,4})|(([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}))$")]

And

^([\w\.\-]+)@([\w\-]+)((\.(\w){2,3})+)$
```

What I am missing to make the patterns work properly ?

If I try the bot using the localhost API and the BotFramework Channel Emulator all the expression work well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens because from Skype email comes as link:

```
{
   "type": "message",
   "id": "1518201259505",
   "timestamp": "2018-02-09T18:34:19.515Z",
   "localTimestamp": "2018-02-10T01:34:19.515+07:00",
   "serviceUrl": "https://smba.trafficmanager.net/apis/",
   "channelId": "skype",
   "from": {
            "id": "29:1e6pgQhUZAJSct6xsOxTh1160QpUF1CXkZXqD4VRDx9A",
            "name": "User"
           },
   "conversation": {
                     "id": "29:1e6pgQhUZAJSct6xsOxTh1160QpUF1CXkZXqD4VRDx9A"
                   },
  "recipient": {
   "id": "28:62516114-227c-436c-8e55-e7dcf50e7474",
   "name": "Bot"
   },
  "membersAdded": [],
  "membersRemoved": [],
  "text": "<a href=\"mailto:mail@ukr.net\">mail@ukr.net</a>",
  "attachments": [],
  "entities": [
  {
    "type": "clientInfo",
    "locale": "en-US",
    "country": "US",
    "platform": "Windows"
   }
  ],
 "channelData": {
  "text": "<a href=\"mailto:mail@ukr.net\">mail@ukr.net</a>"
   }
 }
```